# python re sub replace values

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I need a python regular expression through which I can replace certain values in the path

```
"path":"C:\Users\admin\Downloads\npp.8.0.Installer.exe"
"path": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Common\Google Updater\Extensions\GoogleUpdaterService.exe"
```

to

```
"path":"<drive>:\Users\<uname>\Downloads\npp.8.0.Installer.exe"
"path": "<drive>:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Common\Google Updater\Extensions\GoogleUpdaterService.exe"
```

The replace values are "<'drive'>" and "<'username'>"(if any username exists in the path).

I am trying with

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0).
```

How can I most easily build a pattern which can replace the above valve ?

Comment: What is your question about your need?

Comment: Why not simply use `str.replace()`?

Comment: How is a regular expression supposed to know that `admin` is a user name but `Google Updater` is not?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: "How can I most easily build a pattern" --> by [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: @mkrieger1 The assumption is any word right next to literal word 'User\' and before next occurrence of '\' can be considered as username.

Comment: This works for replacing users with `<uname>`: https://regex101.com/r/Ti2Eqr/1/ 
          This works for replacing drives with `<drive>`: https://regex101.com/r/uclhE5/1

Comment: @LuisAFK Thanks for the expressions. The expression for drive isn't working when the path is in between quotes (" "). https://regex101.com/r/NpJ6Vx/1.

Comment: @no1 fixed, accepts with and without: https://regex101.com/r/NpJ6Vx/2

Comment: @LuisAFK It isn't working for the string "path":"C:\Users\admin\Downloads\npp.8.0.Installer.exe" to "path":"<drive>:\Users\admin\Downloads\npp.8.0.Installer.exe"

Comment: @no1 fixed: https://regex101.com/r/NpJ6Vx/3